# What is 'The right way' to authorize this REST API request?

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I'm building a REST Api and I'm sitting here with a problem. By no means I am an expert on this subject, so I want to learn how to address REST architecture the 'right way' (or at least in a way that makes sense).

I'm building a web application with a Angular Frontend and a laravel-based, RESTfull backend API. The app has these 3 tables: Albums, Posts and Comments. A user can write a post in an album if he/she is a member of that album.

A user can be invited to become member of an album and then see all it's posts and the comments for those posts. If an user isn't (invited to be) a member of an album it can't comment on posts in that album.

In other words: if a user comments on a post, the post has to be from an album the user is a member of.

**My dilemma is: how do I check/authorize this request?**

My Eloquent relationships are as follows:

- The user table has a many to many relationship with albums
- Albums have many posts
- Posts have many comments

The incoming request is a POST request that has 2 parameters:

- album_id (the album that the post is in)
- post_id (for the post that is being commented on)
- body (The actual comment itself)

The author for the post is retrieved via Auth::user();

My initial thoughts for addressing this problem are:

1. I check for all the albums a user is a member of
2. Build an array of al the ID's of the found albums the user is a member of
3. Check if the post_id parameter is in that array
4. If it's not, the user can't comment and if it is, the user can comment

My code so far:

```
// Validate the Request Body
$input = $this->request->only([ 'album_id', 'post_id', 'comment' ]);

$validator = Validator::make( $input, [

    'album_id'  => 'required|integer',
    'post_id'   => 'required|integer',
    'comment'   => 'required',

]);

// Authorize the Request
$albumIdList = Auth::user()->albums()->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();

$postIdList = Post::whereIn( 'album_id', $albumIdList )->select('id')->get()->toArray();

if( ! in_array($this->request->get('post_id'), $albumIdList))
    return abort(403);

// Store the new comment
$comment = Comment::create([

    'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
    'post_id'   => $input['post_id'],
    'comment'   => $input['comment'],

]);

return $comment;
```

I think this is working properly, but what if a album has 1000 posts? Building the array wit all post ID's becomes really intensive for the server... How would a professional company (like Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest) tackle this in their web application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) and `exists` methods:

```php
$allowed = Auth::user()->albums()->whereHas('post', function ($query) {
    $query->where($this->request->only('post_id'));
})->exists();
```

---

Also, there's no reason to pass in the `album_id`. Your code can be reduced to this:

```php
$this->validate($this->request, [
    'post_id' => 'required|integer',
    'comment' => 'required',
]);

$allowed = Auth::user()->albums()->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
    $query->where($this->request->only('post_id'));
})->exists();

if (! $allowed) return abort(403);

$input = $this->request->only('post_id', 'comment');

return Comment::create($input + ['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
```

---

If you want to clean this up further, you should look into Laravel's [authorization facilities](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization).